# Unable to load storage tables in azure storage explorer

Tags: azure-table-storage, azure-storage-explorer

I have installed Azure storage explorer(1.12.0) and I have connected my azure account successfully. But Storage table is not loading properly. It was showing **connection econnrefused** exception.

Note: I have another resource group with same subscription, I can able to load tables from that resource group. Any idea about this issue?
[image]

Comment: Can you please check the storage account type? Not all storage accounts (like Blob Storage) supports tables. That could be the reason.

Comment: Hi Gaurav  thanks for your update. But it seems like Azure Storage Explorer issue because I can able to see tables and values in Azure Portal under "Storage Explorer()Preview"

Comment: Try to delete the `%AppData%/Roaming/StorageExplorer` folder, then  restart storage explorer .

Comment: How do you connect to this storage? subcription, con string, sas uri or account name and key?

Comment: Do you behind a proxy?

Comment: Hi, have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

First, you can follow the offcial troubleshouting doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-explorer-troubleshooting?tabs=Windows%2C1904#unable-to-retrieve-children-error-message

> If you're connected to Azure through a proxy, verify that your proxy
>   settings are correct. If you're granted access to a resource from the
>   owner of the subscription or account, verify that you have read or
>   list permissions for that resource.

Second, you can try to delete data from %appData/StorageExplorer and reinstall storage explorer.

Have a check of whether 443 port is open. Or may be it just network instability...